# Grouping not working in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, fieldcollapsing

I have installed and configured solr 3.6.0 with tomcat container. I have created the index of solr example docs. I want to apply grouping functionality on that.
I have applied grouping query according to below document: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing
and I don't see the field collapsing. I mean I see the results, but not the grouping. My understanding is it should work. I have chaged below line in `solrconfig.xml`.

```
<searchComponent name="query" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.CollapseComponent" />
```

in my solr home, all the fields are indexed and stored.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include a searchComponent in your `solrconfig.xml`.  If you're using 3.6, the grouping functionality you need is included standard.

Simply:

- Remove the line you added to solrconfig.xml and restart Solr.
- Run your query with the additional parameters `group=true&group.field=group_field`

(make sure the `group_field` you're using is indexed in your schema)

Comment: hi..i have done this way much before..but it was not working..so still it is not working..i have created index this way,.curl 'http://localhost:8085/solr/update/' -H 'Content-type:text/xml' --databinary
"@lu-example-1.xml"